# Drush failing on Vagrant with Mavericks

Tags: vagrant, osx-mavericks, drush

I've just gotten a new MacBook Pro running Mavericks.

We're using Vagrant with Puppet on this project and when I do `vagrant up` I get this error

```
err: /Stage[main]/Drush::Git::Drush/Exec[first drush run]: Failed to call refresh: /usr/bin/drush status returned 255 instead of one of [0] at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/modules-0/drush/manifests/git/drush.pp:32
```

Which prevents me from doing anything with Drush while inside `vagrant ssh`

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue on this was that we were using the Drush master branch within our Puppet profile and at that time, the Drush master branch was failing. Fell back to 6.x and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: http://davidwalsh.name/fixing-vagrant-errors

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is VirtualBox related though. Vagrant itself does seem to work, it's the specific Drush Puppet module in the manifest that seems to be failing.

Comment: Ah right ok, sorry. Have you tried not using Drupal? Might be worth a shout?